# subversion & tortoiseSVN: How to bring more trunk folders and files into an active branch?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

We branched a subset of our subversion trunk. Not all the necessary folders were included and for one parent folder it's sub-folders were branched but not the parent folder itself. I need to get the branch structure to mirror the trunk and I'm not certain how to go about it.

Concerns:

- Creating new folders in place and moving folders may confuse subversion
- Copying files from trunk to the branch may confuse subversion
- Improper changes causing subsequent forward integration problems
- Improper changes causing subsequent branch re-integration problems
- Losing new work on the branch
- There is concurrent work against the trunk and it is a separate functional/software revision at this point

  - Please refrain from commenting on this version control plan, I already know what you're going to say.

```
trunk
   /doc
   /src
      /srcA
      /srcB
      ...

LongBranch
   //   /doc folder is not here, but needs to be.

   //  src folder is not here but its sub-folders are

   /srcA    // I need these under their parent /src folder
   /srcB
   ...
```

Comment: Copying folders from trunk to branch should be fine, not sure what you mean by 'may confuse subversion'? It'll keep track of the changes to branch and trunk separately (and you can always check out a previous revision if something does go wrong).

Comment: by "confuse subversion" I mean when it comes time to merge (either direction) that subversion does not see copied files as having been branched and might require some manual intervention.

Comment: See what you're saying but in the working copy (where they're changed) they're separate files, this will be reflected in the repository once the changes are committed. You could always copy the repository and test on the copy to confirm it works if you're worried?

Comment: "go ahead, give it a shot; we have a team of experts standing by." We made changes directly in the repository, via tortoiseSVN, creating folders and moving entire folder structures as needed to make our active branch look like the trunk structurally. And its looking ok. I also feared my working copy would "go stupid" and I'd have to create a new, fresh working copy. In any event my backup is local version control using Mercurial.